# Angular 2/4: How do you reference path parameters in the route data?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Is there a way to reference the path parameters in the data of the route?

I have a generic route that looks like this: 

`{ path: "Servicing/:type/:id", component: BaseComponent, data: { title: "Servicing" } },`

I use the `title` property to set the title at the top of the page (and the `<title>` tags).  So rather than have to write some special code where this title handling has to know certain pages that it should prepend the `type` path param, I'd like do something like this:

`{ path: "Servicing/:type/:id", component: BaseComponent, data: { title: <type> + " Servicing" } },`

Comment: I posted an answer below, but can you explain the "why" behind manipulating your menu this way instead of pulling the active route into the component and manipulating the model data there? I guess I don't understand what it is you're trying to accomplish outside of the component architecture.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It seems to be a fairly common approach for SEO when you're using ASP.net core as your server instead of express.  I can't remember which exact example I followed but the starter made by Mark Pieszak from angular does the same thing (check the routing): https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/blob/master/Client/app/app.module.ts
I'll reword the question.  The menu part wasn't meant to throw you off, I just have a navigation hamburger menu in the top left and beside that I display the title of the page you're currently on. But I just want to set the page title

Answer (score 0):

You really should be manipulating the menu content within the component that it resides within. The router isn't "really" built to handle logic outside of routing. That said the easiest thing to do would be to update the content within the menu component upon a route change.

You would need to import the router using `ActivatedRoute` and tapping into it's parameters like this:

**basecomponent.component.ts**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private _ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {

    // Subscribe to route parameter observable.
    this._ActivatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        _Params => {
            this.type = _Params['type'];
            this.id = _Params['id'];
        }
    )
}
```